# My jquery does not work. Some symbol seems to be missing and I have no clue what

Tags: jquery

Dreamweaver and Jsfiddle keeps telling me there is an error in my code. What is missing? Semicolon? Brackets? Im really confused!

```
if(jQuery('.home').data('clicked')) {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-1").toggleClass("blocks");
        $(".b1").toggleClass("blockss");
        $(".content").addClass("content-removed");

        $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".products").removeClass("item-active");

    });
    } else {
        $(".content").removeClass("content-removed");
    }
```

Updated:

```
if($('.home').data('clicked')) {
    $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
    $(".block-1").toggleClass("blocks");
    $(".b1").toggleClass("blockss");
    $(".content").addClass("content-removed");

    $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
    $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
    $(".products").removeClass("item-active");

} else {
    $(".content").removeClass("content-removed");
}
```

Comment: The `});` doesn't seem to correspond to anything.

Comment: Please include the exact error message. It Will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Theres normally a line number associated with a JavaScript error, but yeah, it's that weird `});` you have for no reason right before the `else`

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing no-conflict `jQuery` with shorthand `$` ?

Comment: The `else` part doesn't really start at the correct place.

Comment: Yep this did the job.   });  Problem is the code doesnt work with if statements. weird

Comment: @DennisR Updated my code. Really? How come? Where should it start? The entire code doesnt work anyways : (. Even with the error fixed

Comment: @Steve I mean to say that you have unexpected ending for the `if` statement by code `});` before the else, then it's obviously not the correct flow for the `else` part.

Comment: @DennisR I added the new code. It should be corrected now :D

Answer (score 2):

Remove the

```
});
```

before the } else {

Answer (score 1):

You got a little problem next to else.

```
if(jQuery('.home').data('clicked')) {
    $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
    $(".block-1").toggleClass("blocks");
    $(".b1").toggleClass("blockss");
    $(".content").addClass("content-removed");

    $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
    $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
    $(".products").removeClass("item-active");
} else {
    $(".content").removeClass("content-removed");
}
```